# Programmatically-created UIViewController crash on "loaded nib but the view outlet was not set"

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, nib

I wanted to create UIViewController programmatically without nib, e.g.:

```swift
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // code...
    }

    // code...
}
```

and used it like this:

```swift
let vc = MyViewController()
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

However, the app crashed:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIViewController
>   _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] loaded the "MyViewController" nib but the view outlet was not set.'

---

This is weird because I don't associate any nib files with this view controller.

Cleaning builds, deleting derived data, deleting the app, restarting simulator, Xcode and my Mac didn't work. Adding `init()` and call `super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)` also doesn't help.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that I *accidentally* have a nib file named `MyView.xib` that is totally unrelated to `MyViewController`, but the system tries to load that!

When we call `MyViewController()` (which calls `init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)`), the system tries to be smart by finding nib file with similar names, from the [`nibName` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname?language=swift):

> ... However, if you do not specify a nib name, and **do not override the
>   loadView() method** in your custom subclass, the view controller
>   searches for a nib file using other means.

According to the doc, it searches for these:

1. MyView.xib
2. MyViewController.xib

Which is bingo and crashes the app!

---

**Solution:**
Always override `loadView` when you create `UIViewController` programmatically to prevent that behavior:

```swift
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    // OVERRIDE THIS TO FIX!
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
    }

    ...
}
```

Want to try? https://github.com/aunnnn/ViewController-Nib-Confusion